# Changing the Contact's(lookup) field using trigger

Tags: trigger, lookup, contact, custom

in case of update or insert of new Object__c, my trigger needs to update the Object__c.Contact.Title in case that the Object__c.Title__c is different . at the moment im changing the entire contact and that is wrong. any ideas how to save the same contact and just change his Title? thanks.
**Objects:**

> ```
> Object__c (child):
> fields: Title__c(text), Name, Contact(standart, lookup), Contact_Title__c(formula)
>
>
> Contact (parent):
> field: Title
> ```

**Code:**

```
trigger ObjectTrigger on Object__c (before update, before insert)
    { 
        Set<String> Titles = new Set<String>(); 
        for (Object__c collectTitles : Trigger.new)
            Titles.add(collectTitles.Title__c); 
    
        List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT id, Title FROM Contact WHERE Title IN :Titles]; 
    
        Map<String, Contact> TitleToContactMap = new Map<String, Contact>();
        for (Contact c : contactList) 
            TitleToContactMap.put(c.Title, c); 
    
        for (Object__c p : Trigger.new)              
            if ( (p.Title__c != null) && (p.Title__c != p.Contact_Title__c)  ) 
                p.Contact__c = TitleToContactMap.get(p.Title__c).id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You were querying for contacts with similar titles, however I see Contact__c is a custom field on your Object__c therefore the answer below uses that relationship because I assume its closer to what you need.  This is untested, but should work or be close.

You'll want to include error handling logic, comments, and test this thoroughly against your org's execution stack and existing features to help handle potential errors, unintended recursion (if any is caused from the dml `update`), etc.

If you are new to salesforce triggers i recommend using Flows instead, which can be turned off generally much quicker than it takes to patch apex code.  Especially because the apex code below is synchronous which means if any exceptions or errors occur in the code below the users would very likely become stuck unless you handle errors in a way that lets them continue or move the code to an async context.

Lastly, this feature needs a test class, for apex code coverage reasons. If you reason away from Flows and must use apex then consider adding a test class for this logic and reformating the code to be less lines to achieve more line coverage.

I hope this helps.

```
trigger ObjectTrigger on Object__c (before update, before insert)
    { 
        Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Object__c obj : Trigger.new){
            contactIds.add(obj.contact__c);
        }
    
        List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Id, Title 
                                    FROM Contact WHERE ID IN :contactIds]; 
    
        Map<Id, String> ContactIdToContactTitleMap = new Map<Id, String>();
        for (Contact c : contactList) {
            ContactIdToContactTitleMap.put(c.Id, c.Title); 
        }
    
        Contact[] contactsToUpdate = new Contact[] {};


        for (Object__c p : Trigger.new){
            if(p.Title__c!= null && (p.Title__c!= ContactIdToContactTitleMap.get(p.contact__c))){
                contactsToUpdate.add(
                    new Contact(
                        Id = p.contact__c,
                        Title = ContactIdToContactTitleMap.get(p.contact__c)
                        ));

            } 
            
         }

         update contactsToUpdate;
    }
```

Comment: i made a few revisions

Comment: Hi, now The Object__c's Contact is really updated with the right Title as i want. but, when i look in** Contacts tab** the title was not updated. thank for your answer

Comment: Did you deploy the trigger to a sandbox? Are you testing in the same sandbox? Query the contact record in anonymous apex or developer console to verify if its being updated.  What URL is shown when you click the contact tab?